# C++ error: terminate call after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, oop, ubuntu, sigabrt

I created a user-defined String class and some file handling function. I tried using g++ on ubuntu to compile this piece of code and gdb to debug several times before. The error was thrown in line

```
s2.diskIn(iflile);
```

Interface:

```
class String {
    long unsigned int len; 
    char *cStr;
public:
    String(const String &);
    explicit String(const char * const = NULL);

    void diskIn(std::ifstream &);
    void diskOut(std::ofstream &);
    const char *getString();
    String operator = (const String);
    ~String();
};
```

Copy constructor

```
String::String(const String &ss) {
    if (ss.cStr == NULL) {
        cStr = NULL; len = 0;
    } else {
        len = ss.len;
        cStr = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy(cStr, ss.cStr);
    }
}
```

Default/ Assignment Constructor

```
String::String(const char * const p) {
    if (p == NULL) {
        cStr = NULL; len = 0;
    } else {
        len = strlen(p);
        cStr = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy(cStr, p);
    }
}
```

Error function:

```
void String::diskIn(std::ifstream &fin) {
    String temp;
    fin.read((char *)&temp.len, sizeof(int));
    temp.cStr = new char[len + 1];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < temp.len; i++) 
        fin.get(temp.cStr[i]);
    temp.cStr[i] = '\0';
    *this = temp;   
}
```

Copy assignment operator

```
String String::operator = (const String ss) {
    if (cStr != NULL) {
        delete[] cStr;
        cStr = NULL;
        len = 0;
    }

    if (ss.cStr != 0) {
        len = ss.len;
        cStr = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy(cStr, ss.cStr);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Destructor

```
String::~String() {
    delete[] cStr;
}
```

```
int main() {
    String s2;
    std::ifstream ifile("document.txt");

    s2.diskIn(ifile); //Error was thrown here
    std::cout << s2.getString() << "\n";
    ifile.close();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Re: `if (cStr == NULL) delete[] cStr;` in the destructor has the test backwards. But the test isn't needed; `operator delete` and `operator delete[]` handle null pointers correctly, so just do the delete. This doesn't cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Can we see your default constructor?  You're reading into `temp.len`, but then using `len` (i.e., not the one you read).

Comment: len == ss.len is wrong, you need to assign, use len = ss.len

Comment: *this = temp uses the copy assignment operator not the copy ctor, please add also the copy assignment operator

Comment: I deleted the default constructor because it threw  ' ambiguous call to overloaded function'

Comment: That's all of my  constructors : a copy one and an asssignment one

Comment: The fact that you deleted the default ctor is already an issue, say that you create a String s, assign nothing, the destructor will try to delete a pointer pointing to garbage most likely.

Comment: The reason I didn't keep my default constructor was after searching in StackOverflow that if the argument passed in the String ::String(const char * const p = NULL) is NULL or nothing, the compiler notified that it didn't know which constructor  to choose.

Comment: `String ::String(const char * const p = NULL)` *is* a default constructor. Please post a [mcve], a random selection of code is not very useful. Having said that, `diskIn` is broken because you don't allocate the correct length. You also need an assignment operator

Comment: Yes, **if** your constructor took `const char*const p = NULL` then it would also act as a default constructor. But yours doesn't have a default argument, so it can't be called with no arguments. Put the default constructor back, or add the default argument. Preferably the former.